# 'wiki_render' did not receive value(s) for the argument(s): 'request'

Tags: python, django, wiki

I try modify django-wiki

function

```
  @register.inclusion_tag('wiki/includes/render.html', takes_context=True)
  def wiki_render(context, article, preview_content=None):

     if preview_content:
      content = article.render(preview_content=preview_content)
     else:
      content = None
```

to look like this

```
 @register.inclusion_tag('wiki/includes/render.html', takes_context=True)
 def wiki_render(context, article, request, preview_content=None):

     if preview_content:
      content = article.render(preview_content=preview_content)
     else:
      content = None
     if request.user.is_authenticated():
      lastname = request.user.last_name
```

But get

```
     'wiki_render' did not receive value(s) for the argument(s): 'request'
```

What i must change to fix error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access `request` object, you can get it from the `context`:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('wiki/includes/render.html', takes_context=True)
def wiki_render(context, article, preview_content=None):
    request = context['request']
    ...
```

Note that this requires `'django.core.context_processors.request'` to be included in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, but this is already a [prerequisite of django-wiki](http://django-wiki.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#configure-template-context-processors).

Check the source of `login_url` tag of [django-wiki](https://github.com/django-wiki/django-wiki/blob/master/wiki/templatetags/wiki_tags.py) for an example.